# NodeJS - Express cannot read property of null

Tags: node.js, json, api, express, mongodb-query

Good day. I am building an API in NodeJs. Below is the method that is giving me the error.

```
exports.getCartItems = (req, res) => {
  Cart.findOne({ user: req.user._id })
    .populate("cartItems.product", "_id name price productPictures")
    .exec((error, cart) => {
      if (error) return res.status(400).json({ error });
      if (cart) {
        let cartItems = {};
        cart.cartItems.forEach((item, index) => {
          console.log(item.product); //This gives result, when I remove everything else
          cartItems[item.product._id.toString()] = {
            _id: item.product._id.toString(),
            name: item.product.name,
            img: item.product.productPictures[0].img,
            price: item.product.price,
            qty: item.quantity,
          };  
        });
        
        res.status(200).json({ cartItems });
      }
    });
  //}
};
```

I get the error

```
      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

However, when I console.log `item.product`, I get results. This is shwon in the image below. Please, what I'm I doing wrong?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: If the line of code that causes the error is this one: `name: item.product.name,`, then the error is telling you that `item.product` is apparently `null`, somewhere in your `.forEach()` loop.  More debugging will tell you when exactly that occurs and give you an idea how to defensively code against it.

Comment: You also probably want to console.log 'cart.cartItems' before the loop to ensure there is no 'null' objects in the array because the null will get thrown if any items don't have that property. You can also place a try catch in your loop and in the catch, console.log the item to see what one has null for name.